# Amazon Lambda unable to import [python windows .pyd pip]

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, pip, aws-lambda, psycopg2

I am trying to write to my PostgreSQL database with AWS Lambda using the python2.7 runtime.  I care very little about how I do this, so if anyone has a different way that I can understand that works, I'd love to hear it.

The method I'm currently trying is to use psycopg2, as this is the only way I know.  In order to do this, I need to upload the psycopg2 module to my environment on AWS Lambda.  [As per instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html), I've created a directory with my source and psycopg2 using `pip install psycopg2 -t ..\my-project`, zipped `my-project`, and uploaded it.

My error message is this from within the AWS Lambda console: `Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named _psycopg`

The code runs on my windows machine. I think the issue is that when I `import psycopg2` from my local windows machine, the `_psycopg` module is being imported from `_psycopg.pyd`, and .pyd files are windows specific.  I may be wrong about this.

I'm really just looking for any way to achieve the desired result described in my first paragraph, but here's a more specific question: How do I tell windows to pip install and compile psycopg2 without using .pyd files?  Is this possible?  Do I have something completely wrong?

I know the formatting of this question is a little unorthodox, I think I've given all the necessary information, let me know if there's anything else I can provide.

Comment: You need to install the package using `pip` for whatever architecture AWS Lambda uses: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Comment: Do you know how to do this using a windows machine?

Comment: Is the best way to just use a virtual machine running linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by opening an ubuntu instance on VirtualBox, pip installing the package there, pulling the relevant folders out, and placing them in `my-project` before zipping and uploading to AWS Lambda.

[See these instructions.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)